# Moving a STL object between processes

Tags: c++, stl

I know this is strange but I'm just having fun.

I am attempting to transmit a `std::map` (instantiated using placement new in a fixed region of memory) between two processes via a socket between two machines: `Master` and `Slave`.  The map I'm using has this `typedef`:

```
   // A vector of Page objects
   typedef
      std::vector<Page*,
           PageTableAllocator<Page*> >
      PageVectorType;

   // A mapping of binary 'ip address' to a PageVector
   typedef
      std::map<uint32_t,
           PageVectorType*,
           std::less<uint32_t>,
           PageTableAllocator<std::pair<uint32_t, PageVectorType*> > >
      PageTableType;
```

The `PageTableAllocator<T>` class is responsible for allocating whatever memory the STL containers may want/need into a fixed location in memory.  E.g., all `Page` objects and STL internal structures are being instantiated in this fixed memory region.  This ensures that both the `std::map` object and the allocator are *both* placed in a fixed region of memory.  I've used GDB to make sure the map and allocator behave correctly (all memory used is in the fixed region, nothing ever goes on the application's normal heap).

Assuming `Master` starts up, initializes all of it's STL structures and the special memory region, the following happens.  `Slave` starts, prints out its version of the page table, then looks for a `Master`.  `Slave` finds a master, deletes its version of the page table, copies `Master`'s version of the page table (and the special memory region), and **successfully** prints it out the `Master`'s version of the page table.  From what prodding I've done in GDB I can perform many read-only operations.

When trying to add to the newly copied `PageTableType` object, `Slave` faults in the allocator's `void construct (pointer p, const T& value)` method.  The value passed in as `p` points to an already allocated area of memory (as per `Master`'s version of the `std::map`).

I don't know anything about C++ object structure, but I'm guessing that object state from `Slave`'s version of the `PageTableType` must be hanging around even after I replace all of the memory that the `PageTableType` and its allocator used.  *My question is if this is a valid concern.  Does C++ maintain some sort of object state outside of the area of memory that object was instantiate din?*

All of the objects used in the map are non-POD.  Same is true for the allocator.

Comment: Where do you store the metadata that determines which part of the shared memory has been allocated?

Comment: I've redefined all calls to memory allocation code (`malloc`, `free`, etc.) in my application.  When a node allocates memory, the offsets are recorded in this `std::map` object.  When `Slave` tries to update the map (post-transmission) it faults.

Comment: That's what I mean. Recorded *where*?

Comment: The `std::map` is instantiated using placement new in another fixed region of memory.

Comment: So, is that other map *also* shared with the client? I'm afraid I might be getting confused about which map you're talking about, because you say "*the* `std::map`" but I think you're describing two different ones.

Comment: There are two regions of memory (both shared with client).  PageTableRegion is a fixed region of memory used to instantiate `PageTableType` (using placement new). PageTableAllocatorRegion is a fixed region of memory used by `PageTableAllocator<T>`.  All these addresses are identical between client/server.  Does that help (also tried to clean up question to make this more clear)?

Comment: are you trying to implement your own shared-memory functionality? have you considered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2131397/1025391)?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Distributed shared-memory, though.  Just for funsies. =)  Thanks that link is interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

> *Does C++ maintain some sort of object state outside of the area of memory that object was instantiated in?*

The answer is *no*. There are no other data structures set up to "track" objects or anything of the sort. C++ uses an explicit memory allocation model, so if you choose to be responsible for allocation and deallocation, then you have complete control.

I suspect there's something wrong in your code somewhere, but since you believe the code is correct you're inventing some other reason why your code might be failing, and following that path instead. I would pull back, and carefully examine everything about the way your code is working right now, and see if you can determine the problem. Although the STL classes are complex (especially `std::map`), they're ultimately just code and there is no hidden magic in there.